# About the limit of $\prod\limits_{k=2}^n (1-\frac{1}{k^3})^k (1+\frac{1}{k^3})^{1-k}$

Tags: products

*Question:*

Does a formula exist for 
$\enspace\displaystyle \prod\limits_{k=2}^n (1-\frac{1}{k^3})^k (1+\frac{1}{k^3})^{1-k}\enspace$ so that it can be seen

that the limit is $\,\displaystyle\frac{1}{3}\,$ for $\,n\to\infty\,$ ?

*Note:*

The input $\enspace\text{prod (1-1/k^3)^k/(1+1/k^3)^(k-1) from k=2 to n}$

with *Wolfram Alpha* gives a complicated term, with which I cannot see any limit.

Also to take the logarithm doesn't look very helpful.

---

EDIT: I thank all for the kind and competent help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can prove via induction or telescopic product that
$$\prod_{k=2}^n\,\left(1-\frac1{k^3}\right)^k\,\left(1+\frac1{k^3}\right)^{1-k}=\frac{\left(n^2+n+1\right)^n}{3\,n^{n+1}\,(n+1)^{n-1}}$$
for all $n=2,3,4,\ldots$.

Comment: So the value of the infinite product is **exactly** one third. Nice observation :D

Comment: That's what I was looking for! Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 5):

Well, $\prod_{k\geq 2}\left(1+\frac{1}{k^3}\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\cosh\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$, hence we may focus on
$$ \prod_{k\geq 2}\left[\frac{1-\frac{1}{k^3}}{1+\frac{1}{k^3}}\right]^k=\exp\sum_{k\geq 2}-2k\,\text{arctanh}\frac{1}{k^3}=\exp\sum_{k\geq 2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{-2}{(2n+1)k^{6n+2}} $$
which can be written as
$$ \exp\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{2\left[1-\zeta(6n
+2)\right]}{(2n+1)}=\exp\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{-2}{2n+1}\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{x^{6n+1}}{(6n+1)!e^x(e^x-1)}\,dx$$
or as
$$ \exp\int_{0}^{+\infty}\frac{-g(x)}{e^x(e^x-1)}\,dx $$
where $g(x)$ is a hypergeometric function and $\frac{g(x)}{e^x(e^x-1)}$ behaves like $\left(2-\frac{x^2}{12}\right) e^{-3x/2}$ in a right neighbourhood of the origin. This leads to the approximation $\approx 0.336233$ for the original product. As shown by Batominovski, the original product is exactly $\frac{1}{3}$ by telescoping. This leads to the identity

$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{\zeta(6n+2)-1}{2n+1}=\frac{1}{2}\log\left(\frac{3}{2\pi}\cosh\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\tag{I}$$
and to the approximate identity
$$ \cosh\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)\approx \frac{2\pi}{3}e^{\frac{104}{81}}.\tag{II}$$

Comment: Thank you very much for your help! --- I am looking for an expression, which makes it possible to see the exact limit. I will check how accurate your approximation is. ;) Maybe it can be refined.

Comment: @user90369: this can be easily turned into WA's output by writing $$\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{6n+1}}{(6n+3)(6n+1)!}=\frac{1}{x^2}\sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{x^{6n+3}(6n+2)}{(6n+3)!}$$ in terms of exponentials through the discrete Fourier transform.

Comment: You first approximation $\frac{1}{2\pi\exp(4/3)}\cosh\left(\frac{\pi\sqrt{3}}{2}\right)$ is about $0.32$ . O.k., that's a good start. I will check the series. :)

Comment: The approximation with the series is $\enspace \displaystyle e^{-2\cdot 0.646305573165355316427673428197459132253272}\enspace\enspace  \cdot\cosh(\pi\sqrt{3}/2)/(2\pi)\enspace$ which is about $1/3$ .

Comment: $(\text{I}):$ Interesting formula. ;)

Comment: How did you get $$\prod_{k=2}^\infty\,\left(1+\frac{1}{k^3}\right)=\frac{1}{2\pi}\,\cosh\left(\frac{\sqrt{3}\pi}{2}\right)\,,$$ though?

Comment: @Batominovski : A short hint: $\enspace\displaystyle 1+\frac{1}{k^3}=\frac{1+\frac{1}{k}}{1+\frac{1}{k-1}} (1+\frac{e^{i2\pi/3}}{k}) (1-\frac{e^{i2\pi/3}}{k-1})\,$ for $\,k>1\,$ , Index shift , $\Gamma(1+x)\Gamma(1-x)=\pi x / \sin(\pi x) $

Comment: Agreed. As an alternative, $$\cosh(\pi x/2)=\prod_{n\geq 0}\left(1+\frac{x^2}{(2n+1)^2}\right)$$ and reindexing.

Answer (score 2):

You can have a good approximation taking logarithms since
$$a_k=k \log \left(1-\frac{1}{k^3}\right)+(1-k) \log \left(1+\frac{1}{k^3}\right)$$ Using Taylor expansions
$$a_k=-\frac{2}{k^2}+\frac{1}{k^3}-\frac{1}{2 k^6}-\frac{2}{3
   k^8}+\frac{1}{3 k^9}+O\left(\frac{1}{k^{12}}\right)$$
$$S_n=\sum_{k=2}^n a_k=\frac{1}{6} \left(-12 H_n^{(2)}+6 H_n^{(3)}-3 H_n^{(6)}-4 H_n^{(8)}+2
   H_n^{(9)}+11\right)$$ where appear generalized harmonic numbers.

Using asymptotics, this would give
$$S_n=\left(\zeta (3)+\frac{\zeta (9)}{3}+\frac{11}{6}-\frac{\pi ^2 \left(9450+15 \pi
   ^4+2 \pi ^6\right)}{28350}\right)+\frac{2}{n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$ Taking the exponential of the first term will give $0.333360$

Comment: That's a good approximation, thanks! --- But I am still looking for a proof for $1/3$ .